# Problems running click command group

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I am having trouble with command groups. I have been following [this guide](http://click.pocoo.org/5/complex/#the-first-child-command).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import click


@click.group()
@click.option("--template-id", prompt="Template ID", help="The template to use.")
@click.option("--lang", prompt="Langcode", help="The language to use.")
def cli(template_id, lang):
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.argument('template-id')
@click.argument('lang')
def upload_translations(template_id, lang):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Running this causes problems:

```
» ~/cli.py upload_translations --template-id=xxxxx --lang=ja 
Template ID: sdf
Langcode: asdf
Error: no such option: --template-id
```

1. Why is click requesting the options? I am already passing that on the command line!
2. Why is there an Error: `no such option: --template-id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--template-id` option is not an option to the `upload_translations` command; it is an option to the base `cli`.  So you would call it like:

```
./cli.py --template-id=xxxxxx --lang=ja upload_translations ...
```

Also, you have a `--lang` option both on `cli` and on `upload_translations`.  Which means this would also be valid:

```
./cli.py --template-id=xxxxxx upload_translations --lang=ja ...
```

That's a bit confusing; you may want to either remove the `--lang` option from one or the other, or give it a different name in one of those two commands if it's not actually the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was confused about arguments and options, and about group arguments/options vs command arguments/options. I thought the group was able to pass options to the command. It is a bit strange, since I am not used to Linux commands to work the way that click is doing: click seems to expect that some options / arguments are given before the command, and some options/arguments after the command. Linux commands are not strict regarding options location.